# Use Fourier's method of separation of variables to solve the problem

Tags: boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

\begin{align}
& u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}-\alpha u \\[6pt]
& u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0, \ \ t>0 \\[6pt]
& u(x,0)=f(x) \\[6pt]
& u_t(x,0)=g(x), \ \ 0<x<L \\[6pt]
& \alpha>0.
\end{align}

Comment: Your thoughts on this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: idk what to do with "−αu"

Comment: You'll need to read up about the "inhomogeneous wave equation".